# Pegar apenas numeros de uma String (Tokenizer)

Tags: java, string, netbeans, token

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto com pilha e fila, e estou em uma parte que preciso pegar o operador e colocar em uma pilha e o numero em uma fila.

Porem não esta dando certo essa parte de pegar o numero, alguem tem uma luz para dar certo, pois o que usei da net não esta dando certo. 
Obs: não esta dando erro!

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here       

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String exp;

    Fila fila = new Fila();
    Pilha pilha = new Pilha();

    int valor;



    try {
        System.out.println("Digite um texto.");

        exp = input.next();


        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(exp, "+-*/^()", true);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

            if (campoNumerico(st.nextToken())) {

                try {
                    valor = Integer.parseInt(st.toString());
                    fila.insere(st);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Numero com formato errado!");
                }

            } else {

                pilha.empilhar(st.nextToken());

            }                 

         //   String delimitador;

         //   Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
        } 

        fila.mostrar();

    } catch(Exception erro) {

    }
     System.out.println("Valores pilha: " + pilha);                    

}

private static boolean campoNumerico(String campo){           
        return campo.matches("[0-9]+");   
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe dois erros, o primeiro é que você está consumindo o *token* durante o `if` e não está armazenando o seu valor. O segundo é que você está passando como argumento para o método `Integer.parseInt` o valor retornado pelo método `toString` da classe `StringTokenizer` ao invés do token.

O correto seria dessa forma:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(exp, "+-*/^()", true);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = st.nextToken();
    if (campoNumerico(token)) {
        try {
            fila.insere(Integer.parseInt(token));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Numero com formato errado!");
        }
    } else {
        pilha.empilhar(token);
    }                 
}
```